# bitcoind keeps crashing / using up all resources

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have a 12 vcpu 24 gb ram vps server running bitcoin core and the daemon will sometimes randomly crash or it will sometimes take up all of the 24gb of ram. Just trying to stop the daemon using the bitcoin-cli freezes the server to the point where I can't even SSH in from a new terminal.

heres my bitcoin.conf (private fields omitted):

```
# Daemon
daemon=1
daemonwait=1

# Core
txindex=1
fallbackfee=0.0001

# RPC
server=1
main.rpcbind=:8332
```

Comment: What kind of RPCs do you invoke?